# Android Buttons are clipping each other in RelativeLayout

Tags: android-button, android-elevation

To make Piano like layout, I've used RelativeLayout and put buttons in such a way that black buttons would overlap white buttons as shown in screenshot below.

[image]

When I click white Buttons, they overlaps Black Buttons.
In HTML there is property named z-Index. Similarly elevation property of Android Button is there but it is not solving the problem. White Buttons should not overlap black buttons while playing Piano. What should I do?

**XML Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/cmbRaag"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"

                    android:width="50dp"
                    android:text="राग"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spnRaag"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"

                    android:width="50dp"
                    android:text="थाट"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tThaat"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"

                    android:width="50dp"
                    android:text="प्रहर"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tPrahar"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"

                    android:width="50dp"
                    android:text="वादी"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tVaadi"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"

                    android:width="50dp"
                    android:text="संवादी"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tSamvaadi"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"

                    android:width="50dp"
                    android:text="वर्ज्य"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tVarjya"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"

                    android:width="50dp"
                    android:text="आरोह"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tAroh"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="103dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"

                    android:width="50dp"
                    android:text="अवरोह"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tAvroh"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chk"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Init Sa" />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/tglScan"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ToggleButton"
                    android:textOff="SCANNING ON"
                    android:textOn="SCANNING OFF" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/show"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="show" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/clear"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="clear" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="721dp"
            android:layout_height="167dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:max="38"
                        android:progress="15" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#673AB7">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w1"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:contentDescription="0"
                        android:tag="1" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w2"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w1"
                        android:contentDescription="1"
                        android:tag="3" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w3"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w2"
                        android:contentDescription="2"
                        android:tag="5" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w4"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w3"
                        android:contentDescription="3"
                        android:tag="6" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w5"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w4"
                        android:contentDescription="4"
                        android:tag="8" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w6"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w5"
                        android:contentDescription="5"
                        android:tag="10" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w7"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w6"
                        android:contentDescription="6"
                        android:tag="12" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w8"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w7"
                        android:contentDescription="7"
                        android:tag="13" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w9"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w8"
                        android:contentDescription="8"
                        android:tag="15" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w10"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w9"
                        android:contentDescription="9"
                        android:tag="17" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w11"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w10"
                        android:contentDescription="10"
                        android:tag="18" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w12"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w11"
                        android:contentDescription="11"
                        android:tag="20" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w13"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w12"
                        android:contentDescription="12"
                        android:tag="22" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w14"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w13"
                        android:contentDescription="13"
                        android:tag="24" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w15"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w14"
                        android:contentDescription="14"
                        android:tag="25" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w16"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w15"
                        android:contentDescription="15"
                        android:tag="27" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w17"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w16"
                        android:contentDescription="16"
                        android:tag="29" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w18"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w17"
                        android:contentDescription="17"
                        android:tag="30" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w19"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w18"
                        android:contentDescription="18"
                        android:tag="32" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w20"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w19"
                        android:contentDescription="19"
                        android:tag="34" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w21"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w20"
                        android:contentDescription="20"
                        android:tag="36" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w22"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w21"
                        android:contentDescription="21"
                        android:tag="37" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/w23"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w22"
                        android:contentDescription="22"
                        android:tag="39" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b1"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-6dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w1"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:contentDescription="0"
                        android:tag="2" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b2"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w2"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:contentDescription="1"
                        android:tag="4" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b3"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-6dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w4"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:contentDescription="2"
                        android:tag="7" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b4"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w5"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:contentDescription="3"
                        android:tag="9" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b5"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w6"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:contentDescription="4"
                        android:tag="11" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b6"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-6dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w8"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:contentDescription="5"
                        android:tag="14" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b7"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w9"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:contentDescription="6"
                        android:tag="16" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b8"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-6dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w11"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:contentDescription="7"
                        android:tag="19" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b9"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w12"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:contentDescription="8"
                        android:tag="21" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b10"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w13"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:contentDescription="9"
                        android:tag="23" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b11"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-6dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w15"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:contentDescription="10"
                        android:tag="26" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b12"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w16"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:contentDescription="11"
                        android:tag="28" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b13"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-6dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w18"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:contentDescription="12"
                        android:tag="31" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b14"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w19"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:contentDescription="13"
                        android:tag="33" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b15"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w20"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:contentDescription="14"
                        android:tag="35" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b16"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w22"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:contentDescription="15"
                        android:tag="38" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```